# Making a variable available across two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, global-variables

I have a Question model that `has_many` Answers (a model), each of which `belongs_to` a Question.

For each Question's `show` page, e.g., /questions/1, or /questions/2, I would like the user to input an answer.

The form is working, but the problem is that it seems the question variable is not carrying through to the answers controller that the form is posting to... thoughts?

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = @question.answers.build
end


class AnswersController < ApplicationController

def create
    @answer = @question.answers.build
    redirect_to 'questions/:id'
end
```

I'm getting an error: undefined method `answers' for nil:NilClass at the @answer = @question.answers.build in the AnswersController create method.

Is it time to use a global variable?

By the way, short version is that I'm trying to do a Quora/ Stack Exchange clone. Is there a tutorial that's already done this because man that would be amazing...

Comment: In your `Question` model do you use `accept_nested_attributes_for :answers`?

Comment: No and I'm not sure what that is, but would that line solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And so it shouldn't. This is definitely not the place for a global variable either.

When you're creating an answer for a question, it should post to something like `/questions/2/answers`, which should point to the AnswersController#create action.

In that action, you can load up the correct question record using `params[:question_id]` (which comes from the URL) and then create the answer for that question.

(you want create and not build in your controller, and also your redirect is incorrect)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm not really sure about implementation. I have `<%= form_for(@answer), :url => url_for(:controller => 'Answers', :action => 'Create') do |f| %>` But that will point to the right controller/action, but not the right URL. Do I need to fundamentally change my routes?

Comment: yes, you do. You also don't need to specify a URL for the form - Rails knows that if `@answer` is a new record, then it should post to the create route, and if it is persisted, then it should post to the update route.

Comment: Ah Ok so this makes sense because I can nest the resources. Though now the form throws an error where it's saying there is no `answers_path` which implies that I need a URL right? Sorry I've never done this before.

Comment: no, it means you need to alter the form so it knows it's posting to a nested resource. Try `form_for [@question, @answer]` (so it knows its looking for answers nested under questions)